# How do you pass the parameter in an event that requires a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Considering this code:

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', function(e){
    // large pile of code
});
```

The 'e' parameter is passed by the on() method. I need to split the code inside this function to a different function, as it is too large. Now, this would work just fine:

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', function(e){
    otherFunction(e, param2, param3);
});
```

But as I'm curious, I was wondering how to do it the following way:

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', otherFunction(e, pararm2, param3));
```

How, if possible, do I accomplish this? If I try it this way, e is undefined in otherFunction(). Notice that I'm passing extra parameters to this function.

Comment: You do `$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', otherFunction);`. And I think you need a selector after the event.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You did not read the question.

Comment: @epascarello What do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either pass it in as data which is available on the event object

```
function myfunc(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}

$("button").on("click", {"a" : "apple", "b" : "box"}, myfunc);
```

or use a closure

```
function myfunc(e,a,b) {
    console.log(a);
}

var x = "apple", y = "box";
$("button").on("click", function(e){ myfunc.call(this, e, x, y) });
```

You could also bind/jQuery.proxy, but you lose "this" pointing to what was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the anonymous function with your function you simply omit the `()` - but your function must take the same params that the anonymous would (`event`, not sure what `param1` and `param2` are):

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', otherFunction);
```

And `otherFunction`:

```
function otherFunction(e) {
    console.log(e); //theres e
}
```

If you want the extra params, you need the anonymous function:

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', function(e){
    otherFunction(e, param2, param3);
});
```

Edit: Corrected, you can use `.bind`

Comment: You are 4 seconds late. Check the comment below the question.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel but he posted an answer while you only commented.

Comment: True, but you still are 4s late.

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV, but I also need to pass extra parameters to the otherFunction, or else it would be too easy to answer. ;)

Comment: @BasR. -- Edited - unfortunately you'll need the anonymous function.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel -- You left a comment... and a comment that didnt give an explanation.

Comment: @tymeJV You are right about it, but do I really need to explain how to use functions?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel -- If the question is about the use of functions, then what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', otherFunction.bind(undefined, pararm2, param3));
```

Note: `this` inside the handler will no longer refer to the clicked element, also supported only from IE9+

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use case for [bound functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

The only problem is that you will need to switch around the order of parameters for `otherFunction`, so that the event is the *last* one.

```
$("#divToBeClicked").on('click', otherFunction.bind(window, pararm2, param3));
```

In this snippet, i bind the context of `otherFunction` to `window` (the default). Then, i specify a default first two parameters for it.

Note that here the context (`this`) of `otherFunction` won't be the element that the handler was called on; but since your original solution of an anonymous function lost it anyways, it doesn't seem like a problem.